# Python PIL save method rotates image

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, image-rotation, piexif

I have a little issue with saving image with PIL. In my Django project I have the following **save** method:

```
from PIL import Image

class Photo:
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photos', upload_to='media/date/photos/', help_text='Photo')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        image = Image.open(self.image)
        image.save(self.image.path)
```

So, here I open the image with PIL and just save it in its default path. But looks like depending on image's EXIF data (metadata) PIL rotates the image before saving it.

For example, I took a picture of a person (I was holding the phone vertically, as normal) and when I saved it, the picture was rotated by 90 degrees to the left. What could be the matter here? It happens only if the Orientation was vertical, nothing bad happens to images taken horizontally. Please help and huge thanks in advance!

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Pkm.jpg),
[Saved image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWire.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own post. Guys, I just came up with idea to use OpenCV instead of PIL. It works very well for me, no image rotation occurs and everything is being uploaded properly. Hope this helps you out. Good Luck!